# Cloning Git Repo and Compiling its C Code via bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

I am trying to automate the cloning of a repository and building its code using a bash script. There are some commands in the script that I believe need to be run with `sudo`. To achieve this, I have decided to run the entire script with `sudo` but drop root privileges for commands where they are not needed, using the method discussed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/970898).

Here's what my script looks like (The actual script is longer, but this is the part that fails):

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
   echo "The script needs to be run as root." >&2
   exit 1
fi

if [ $SUDO_USER ]; then
    real_user=$SUDO_USER
else
    real_user=$(whoami)
fi

# Install the Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent
sudo -su $real_user git clone https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent.git /home/$real_user/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent
sudo -su $real_user mkdir /home/$real_user/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build
sudo -su $real_user cd /home/$real_user/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build
sudo -su $real_user cmake ..
sudo -su $real_user make
make install
ldconfig /usr/local/lib/
sudo -su $real_user cd
```

Compared to what is stated in [the resource quoted above](https://askubuntu.com/a/970898), I changed the `sudo -u $real_user` command to `sudo -su $real_user`, otherwise I get the error `sudo: cd: command not found`, for example.

I run the script like so:

```
chmod u+x setup.sh
sudo bash setup.sh
```

However, when I run the script, I encounter this error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

It seems like the `cmake ..` command is not being run in `/home/$real_user/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build`, but instead in `/home`.

My primary question is: **Why is the `cd` command preceding `cmake ..` not effective?**

I have also tried changing the working directory with `pushd` and `popd`, but this was not successful either.

Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `cd` like that just won’t work. It doesn’t change the working directory of the parent process. If your `sudo` has the `--chdir`/`-D` option you could use that.

Comment: `if [ $SUDO_USER ]` is very problematic.  If you mean `if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]`, you should be explicit and write that.  But you should probably just replace the entire if clause with `real_user=${SUDO_USER:-$(whoami)}` and stop worrying about quotes and the foibles of `test`

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting, why aren´t you just making something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash 
if  [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: This script should be executed with sudo!"
    exit 1
fi

# Install the Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent
git clone https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent.git /home/<your/user>/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent
mkdir /home/<your/user>/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build
cd /home/<your/user>/Repos/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/build
cmake ..
make
make install
ldconfig /usr/local/lib/
```

This way, if you just run the script as sudo it should work, and you just need to use sudo inside the script with the lines that need privileges.